# Prove a property of a function H based on the definition provided

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Define $$H(n) = \begin{cases}{}
0 & n\leq 0\\
1 & n = 1 \textrm{ or } n = 2\\
H(n-1) + H(n-2) - H(n-3) & n>2\\
\end{cases}$$

Prove $\forall n\geq 1$ that $H(2n) = H(2n-1) = n$.

---

Maybe I'm just an idiot but I approached this question by drawing a graph. Assuming H= n. But this disproves as when $n\leq 0\\$ then y= 0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions: Prove by induction. None of this makes sense: "I approached this question by drawing a graph. Assuming H= n. But this disproves as when n≤0 then $y= 0.$" Who cares what happens when $y<0$? You are only asked to prove it for natural numbers, so nothing is disproved.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the general rule for solving linear recurrences, and note that $x^3-x^2-x+1=(x+1)(x-1)^2$ to note that the general formula must be $an+b+c(-1)^n$ for some $a,b,c$. Then solve for $a,b,c$ to get an explicit formula. I'd guess $a=1/2$ :)

Comment: This was never covered in class. I'll do some self studying and try to figure out things according to what you said. I'll ask again here if I am still confused :)

Comment: You haven't covered induction, either?

Comment: We have but not linear recurrences. I am sorry if I am sounding incredibly dumb right now.

Comment: Proof by induction is just base case, hypothesis and inductive step. That shouldnt be an issue once I completely understand how to approach the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in which it’s easier to use so-called strong induction: assume as your induction hypothesis that $H(2n)=H(2n-1)=n$ for each $n<m$, and use this induction hypothesis to show that $H(2m)=H(2m-1)=m$. You’ll want to do this in two parts, one for $H(2m)$ and one for $H(2m-1)$. For the latter, for instance, you can argue that

$$\begin{align*}
H(2m-1)&=H(2m-2)+H(2m-3)-H(2m-4)\\
&=H\big(2(m-1)\big)+H\big(2(m-1)-1\big)-H\big(2(m-2)\big)\\
&\overset{*}=(m-1)+(m-1)-(m-2)\\
&=m\;,
\end{align*}$$

as desired. The starred step is where I used the induction hypothesis. Note that the very first step is valid only if $2m-1>2$, i.e., $2m>3$ or, since $m$ is an integer, $m\ge 2$. This means that in order to get the induction off the ground, so to speak, you’ll have to verify the result for $m=1$ separately; that will be your base case for this part of the induction.

I’ll leave the induction step for $H(2m)=m$ to you.